# Locating Layout/Template - Magento

Tags: magento

I need a little bit of guidance. im new to Magento and getting lost with the Templates/Layout structure when it comes to design of a custom theme.

From my understanding there are two types of blocks:

Structure Blocks and Content blocks.

Structure blocks define the structure of the site and Content blocks call .phtml template files to populate the structure blocks with content (please correct me if im wrong).

I have an area that i would like to update, when i turn on the debugging in magento i am advised that the area that i wish to update is located at:

frontend\meigeetheme\default\template\meigee/meigeewidgets/grid_2.phtml

Essentially what i would like to do is get a Categories menu in this area. I expected to find the structural block in a folder within the layout directory called meigee, but i am unable to find any .xml document that represents the defining structure that this template is called in to.

Any idea how i go about it?

All advice and criticisms welcome.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oki doki, so doing my research i found a very useful peace of code.  I would like to give credit to user: djdy.

If you include within a .phtml file:

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->getTemplate();
```

obviously:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->getTemplate(); ?>
```

it will do a nice little echo of the layout being used.

Proved quite helpful in resolving my task.  It seemed that grid_2.phtml was being loaded within:

```
frontend\meigeetheme\default\template\page\1column.phtml
```

then according i was able to add the block i needed in page.xml and call using getChildHtml.  Hope this helps!